# SetState doesn't work properly React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, firebase-storage, use-state

I have the following code currently:

```
const uploadImage = async () => {
    console.log('Hello2');
    console.log(media.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < media.length; i++) {
      const image = media[i];
      const uri = image.source;
      const response = await fetch(uri);
      const blob = await response.blob();
   
      const storageRef = storage
        .ref()
        .child(`listing/${auth.currentUser.uid}/${Math.random().toString(36)}`);
      const task = await storageRef.put(blob);
      const downloadUrl = await task.ref.getDownloadURL();
      console.log('download URL is:');
      console.log(downloadURL);
      setUrls([...urls, downloadURL]);
      console.log('url added');
      console.log(urls.length);
    }
    console.log('Process finished');
    console.log(urls.length);
    if (urls.length == media.length) {
      alert('All images uploaded');
    }
  };
```

In this function I am essentially trying to populate my "urls" array however somehow whenever I run the code it doesn't seem to populate the urls array. Upon console logging everything, the problem isn't the downloadURL as I get a valid value for that, but somehow nothing gets added to the urls array.

I have used similar code below to populate the "media" array and don't seem to be having any trouble with that which is why I don't know why the code for setURLs is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 const openLibrary = async () => {
    const {status} = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
    if (status !== 'granted') {
      alert('Sorry, we need camera roll permissions to make this work!');
    }
    const image = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
    console.log(image);
    // console.log('Media length is: ' + `${media.length().toString()}`);
    if (!image.cancelled) {
      // console.log('Media length is: ' + media.length());
      console.log('Hello');
      setMedia([...media, {source: image.uri, type: image.type}]);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState()` does not always immediately update.
try this

```js
//variable To Save Data Immediately.
const urlArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < media.length; i++) {
    urlArray.push(yourDownloadUrl)
}

setUrls(urlArray);
```

the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) say that

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the updater argument below.